# Is introducing a ragdoll kitten to resident ragdoll cat in a new house different from other breeds

Tags: cats, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

I wanted to get opinions on introducing a new ragdoll kitten to our 1-year old ragdoll. I’ve been getting some conflicting information on the internet.

So we just moved into our new home 2 weeks ago, I don’t think our current ragdoll has quite made it his own yet (i.e. he doesn’t rub against the furniture or use his new cat tree like in my old house). We are getting our new ragdoll kitten either today or tomorrow, the new kitten is our current cat’s half-brother (same father). I’ve done my research and know the safe space, smell swapping, caged introduction, supervised playtime methods.

We only have about a month where at least 1 person can watch them full time, if we both go back to work and they are not used to each other we will need to lock the new kitten in his safe space (which we don’t want to do). Our current cat is very affectionate and playful. He’s been introduced to our friends domestic shorthair, our ragdoll instantly wanted to play but the other cat was hissing at him. Our cat has also been introduced to lots of people and dogs so I feel like he is well socialised.

I was wondering if ragdolls take to new kittens faster than other cats?
 Will being in a new house help (everything doesn’t smell like our old cat)?

**EDIT, my experience with introducing a 10 week old ragdoll kitten to 1 year old ragdoll.**

I’ve had the new kitten for 10 days now, my experience with introducing them. 
The new kitten was isolated for about 1.5 days, by the end of the first 24 hours our resident cat kept trying to get into the room with the new kitten.

Day 2, we allowed the cats into the same room while we observed. The kitten was very curious but resident cat didn’t want anything to do with him. Kitten was still isolated while we slept/didn’t have time to observe them.

Day 3/4, the resident cat started to play with the new kitten still kept separate while we slept.

Day 6, we finally felt safe allowing the cats in the same room as we slept.

Day 8, cats are very happy playing/grooming each other, they also slept in the same cat cave. We’ve leave them alone for few hours at a time. My only concern at the moment is that our resident cat is 4-5x heavier than the new kitten, will be a lot more confident leaving them alone once the new kitten gets a little bigger.

Comment: Related, but not duplicates [Recommendations for introducing kittens to adult cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/83/recommendations-for-introducing-kittens-to-adult-cats) | https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/recommendations-for-introducing-adult-cats-to-newly-adopted-adult-cats

Comment: @InlovingmemoryofDyani I was after some ragdoll specific answers, those steps are for more common cat species. Ragdolls don't tend to act like other cats in a lot of ways so i wanted to know if the process is any different.

Comment: Yep ragdolls are different. OK. Let me know if you're happy with the title. Tweak if to show the emphasis of the difference between this and the dupes.

Comment: Thank you for information. It was very helpful. I am thinking about doing exactly what you did. I would think that the same breed cats (Ragdolls) would bond quicker than non- breeded cats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every cat has its individual level of sociability along a spectrum, but ragdolls tend strongly toward the pro-social end. They're not unique, but they definitely aren't "normal" either.

That doesn't mean ragdolls (or other very pro-social cats) won't benefit from the isolation and introduction processes. However, they will likely get through each step much faster, perhaps days rather than weeks for average cats or months (if ever) for anti-social ones.

Also, cats tend to be more accepting of kittens, which are clearly not a threat, than they are of adult cats. The kitten may still be scared of the adult cat, but since the adult cat will be more curious than either aggressive or defensive, that should pass quickly as well.

The added stress of a new home at the same time complicates things, which might slow progress back down a bit, but even with that factor it's hard to imagine two ragdolls not being friends (or at least friendly enough to leave together unsupervised) within a month.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did think our cats took to each-other much faster than what i expected. they started playing in a few days!