# Bringing a very scared cat home

Tags: cats, feeding, house-moving

Yesterday I picked up a cat from a lady off Craigslist, he was scared of course and she said it was from outside (he's an indoor cat). He did come from a home with 6 other animals I should add. I set him up in my downstairs bathroom since it's not used much, litter,toys,food,etc. He stayed wedged between the toilet and wall all day and some of the night I assume because he's moved to the sink and I can now see he's actually peed on himself. Poor thing is so scared he's only moved that one time in almost 24 hours. Do I just continue to keep him closed in the room or should I be doing something else?
Update: I gave him half a bath, just enough to wash his paws and underbelly and put him back into his room. He did seem more interested in my upstairs but once back downstairs retreated back behind the toilet. He still doesnt seem to have ate or drank anything but did go and sniff the food on his own accord when I brought him back from the bath.

Comment: For your interest: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/480/how-can-i-manage-a-big-change-in-my-cats-environment

Comment: Here is a collection of similar (answered) questions: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/how-long-will-my-new-cat-stay-hidden